# Adding new acces config on SSH Connection

Tags: gcloud

I have a problem on my Google Cloud Platform account
In SSH connection, I can delete my existing access config but can not add new one. When I run the command below the sceen is waiting and noting happeninig.
However, in Cloud Shell, I did not encounter any problem,  I can both delete existing access config and add new one.

Could you help me to add new access config via ssh?

Command: gcloud compute instances add-access-config dev-instance --access-config-name "external-nat"  --zone=us-west1-b

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is you are issuing this command from a SSH'ed instance. If this is the case, please note by issuing the delete command you are actually removing your instance's external IP address and your SSH connection will be lost.

Both add and delete command will work from the cloud shell since it is out of your instance.